# Updating wordpress permalinks to use https://

Tags: permalinks

I had a WordPress Mutlisite network for my site but after months of struggling with it, I turned it back into a single WordPress install, which was quite easy. However, I'm trying to get some new posts going but they keep on adding extra characters to them. When hovering over the title instead of it being `www.mydomain.com/blog/blog-title` it's `www.mydomain.com/blog/www.mydomain.com/blog-title/`.

I've seen that my permalinks don't have the `http://` in front of them and I'm not sure how to update that to the correct way.

My current permalink structure:

[image: I've looked through Google and here b]
but I haven't seen anything that talks about updating this first part.

UPDATED**

Under Settings > General this is what my site title and address look like:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC6r5.png]

Comment: What do you have under Settings > General > WordPress address and Site address?

Comment: @Milo I have updated my question to show you a screenshot of what is there. Thanks!

Comment: Your Site Address doesn't have `http://` in front of it. WordPress shouldn't even let you enter that as Site Address without giving you an error message that it's invalid.

Comment: And it's just as easy as that! Want to make that an answer and then I can mark it as such? Weird how wordpress let me do that without the http://